# SMS com link do GoogleMaps não é enviado

Tags: android, sms

Trabalho com envio de SMS com o link do GoogleMaps, mas em alguns casos, o telefone não envia, não consigo saber o motivo, outros links são enviados normalmente.

Segue a imagem da mensagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de uma ajuda para resolver esta questão. E, importante, a idéia de utilizar o SMS é para não ser obrigatório a internet.

Segue o código que utilizo para a geração:

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + latitude + "," + longitude;
    if (!preferences.getNumber(activity).equals("")) {
        smsBody.append(Uri.parse(uri));
        String telefone1 = preferences.getNumber(activity);
        try {
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(telefone1, null, msgASerEnviada, null, null);
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(telefone1, null, smsBody.toString(), null, null);//mensagem com o link
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Mensagem enviada para " + telefone1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Há algo errado, por favor verifique o número enviado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    }//Na edição foi adicionada mais uma barra.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing the http: //